Does it make sense to separate an analog and digital ground plane in the Eurorack modules?
Eurorack synthesizer is quite a specific standard.

centralized power supply unit,
modules are connected to the backplane using IDC ribbons - that means parasitics,
they are patched with external cables - that means current loops.
In general - not very EMC friendly environment.

If there is a module that has some kind of DSP IC and DAC/analog electronics - does it make sense to split digital and analog ground considering all the things I mentioned? The common point for analog ground would be the module input.

could you add a block diagram to clearify the situation? And maybe specify what you optimization target is. Low EMI or EMS - so are you worried about your device emitting energy - then split grounds are to be avoided in my experience. Or should your device have a high immunity to immission? Then split grounds could be an option.

It depends on details. It's a very generic question with no specific answer.
If you split the planes, you need the analog and digital plane to be tied together under the chip that converts between digital and analog.
So you might as well just use one plane.
This is usually better in regards passing tests how the device emits or gets distuebed by electromagnetic interference.
It might still make sense to use the analog-digital interface chip as the point of star grounding though.
Or slot the ground areas so that digital currents don't travel to analog side and analog currents don't travel over digital currents. Usually slotted ground has gone out of the trend now as it may cause more problems than solve.
The point is that there are many other ways to solve grounding in a way that both minimizes analog interference and passes radiation and immunity tests well.
